# Finding the range of a function in polar form

Tags: functions, polar-coordinates

Find the range of $\theta$ for the portion of line $y=x-1$ in the range   $0\le x \le \infty$.

I was trying:
Let:  $y=x-1$ in polar form:
\begin{align*}
x &= r \cos\theta \\
y &= r \sin\theta \\
r &=\frac{1}{\cos\theta-\sin\theta}.
\end{align*}

We see that when $\theta = \pi/4$, $r$ is undefined.
And we reach a maximum at $\theta = 0$?

$$\pi/4<\theta<0$$

for the portion of the line this is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polar formula is good, but you got the range of $\theta$ wrong. The line starts at point $(-1,0)$, which has polar coordinates $r=1,\theta=-\pi/2$; then it moves upward away from the origin. Every ray springing from the origin, which is a set of the form $\{\theta=\theta_0\}$ with $\theta_0>-\pi/2$, intersects the line, as long as $\theta_0<\pi/4$, because $\theta=\pi/4$ is a ray parallel to the line (slope $=1$). Therefore, the correct range is $-\pi/2 < \theta < \pi/4$.

(Of course, you can add $2\pi$ to both endpoints and get another valid range, but I'm choosing to let $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi)$.)